# Send a remote media file via iMessage App

Tags: ios, swift, imessage-extension

In my iMessage App I'm trying to send a remote video file. From the documentation I can read that the property `mediaFileURL` in `MSMessageTemplateLayout` object should be the right point where to set the URL

> The media file URL must be a file URL

This is how I'm creating the `MSMessage` instance

```
let message = MSMessage()
message.shouldExpire = false

let layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()
layout.mediaFileURL = self.videoURL

message.layout = layout
```

But, when I call the `insertMessage` method, I can't get the correct message entity (no video included)

`conversation.insertMessage(message, completionHandler: nil)`

I've read somewhere (not an official source) that the URL should be a local URL, is that true?

Thanks in advance for any help

**ADDING**

I'm even trying to download the content and set the local URL, but I'm having the same behavior

This is the quick implementation I tried

```
let fileURL = storeDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("video-file.mov")!

_ = try? NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(fileURL.path!)

Alamofire.download(.GET, self.videoURL) { _, _ -> NSURL in
    return fileURL
}.response { _, _, _, error in
    print("Error: \(error)")
    layout.mediaFileURL = fileURL
    print("File URL: \(fileURL)")
    message.layout = layout
    completion(.success(message))
}
```

Of course, the error is `nil` and the file path is a valid local path that references a valid video file (I can reproduce it by going at that path)

**SOLVED**:

For anyone is experiencing this problem, please make sure to **download** the media file firstly. It's not mentioned in the documentation, but it's mandatory. Then, even if in the documentation the audio file is mentioned, a normal mp3 file doesn't work at all. Still don't know what's the specification regarding the **audio** file.

After that, make sure your result is fine: sending the media file in the `MSMessageLayout` means that it's muted and you've to handle the detail view when it's tapped. Consider to use the `insertAttachment` method of `MSConversation` instead.

Comment: How exactly do you mean you have to handle the detail view when its tapped?

Comment: The `MSMessage` with an audio/video file inside aren't played on the iMessage transcript view. When the receiver (or the sender) tap on the message, you receive a call in your iMessage app view controller as a normal message @naomimichiko

Comment: Ok so you handle playing the audio in the didSelect: method?

Comment: No, I just used the `insertAttachment` method and I'm not using the `MSMessage` instance at all. In this way, the media file is handled as a normal media file sent via iMessage @naomimichiko

Comment: I see, I see. Thanks, I have gotten it to work using insertAttachment as well but my client wants to be able to use the MSMessageTemplateLayout to display a title and subtitle :/ Was hoping you had gotten a way to send an audio file with mediaFileURL to work. Thank you!

Comment: layout.mediaFileURL = self.videoURL does it autoplay the videos?

Comment: Can either Luca or Naomi please expand your use of insertAttachment and how that is received? I'm sending with insertAttachment and don't see how to get the data on the receiver side.